# PHP foreach div table pagination simple next previous

Tags: php, html, foreach, jquery-pagination

```
foreach($list as $fll){

    echo "<li>".$fll['name']."-".$fll['score']."</li>"; 

}
```

Name1-66 Name2-63 Name3-17 Name4-16 Name5-15 Name6-14

I want to show that image url below.

[image]

Comment: And what have you tried so far?

Comment: I do not know how to do that. Sorry for my English.

Comment: Amazing, I think the software development industry now hires people without any coding knowledge and forces them to simply outsource the development to SO.